# Opening .e00 file in QGIS with attached table

Tags: qgis, advanced-license-level

I'm trying to open an .e00 raster hosted at (http://www.soilinfo.psu.edu/index.cgi?soil_data&conus&data_cov&poros&datasets&lam) in QGIS. I am able to open it, but I need to add in the supplementary .e00 INFO TABLE too, which QGIS tells me is not a valid raster or vector format?

Comment: maybe it's  a triangulation, this format can store raster or mesh - perhaps ask on https://github.com/lutraconsulting/MDAL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saga GIS is installed with QGIS and will import the stand-alone E00 tables you listed. "Import ESRI E00 File" is located at Import/Export,ESRI E00 Tool Library. Once imported,you can export the table to dbf,txt,csv. 32bit Saga is normally installed at C:\Program Files (x86)\QGIS 3.4\apps\saga-ltr\Saga_gui.exe